# What is $\eta$ in this definition?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

In this definition on differentials in my handbook there is a part that states the following:

Since $$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0 } {\Delta f\over \Delta x} = f'(x) $$

We can say that

$${\Delta f \over \Delta x} = f'(x) + \eta$$ with

$$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \eta = 0$$

But what is $\eta$ here exactly? I can't seem to find any definition or something for this symbol anywhere, not in my book or on the web :/. Or is it just a random variable? Any help would be great!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$η=η(x,Δx)$ is exactly the difference of difference quotient and differential. The smaller the step size $Δx$, the smaller this error gets.

In an equivalent form this is also called the Weierstraß decomposition 
$$
f(x+Δx)=f(x)+f'(x)·Δx+η_f(x,Δx)·Δx
$$
and expresses that all of the linear content of $f$ at $x$ is contained in the derivative value.

Comment: Thanks! This along with the rest of my course makes for a sensible explanation :D